# I do not understand what is jar and class-name in this example code

Tags: hadoop, merge, hdfs, sqoop

I'm trying to merge the incremented data on hdfs using sqoop, this is the sample code I found on google https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2017/02/28/typical-scenario-sqoop-incremental-import-merge/
I do not understand what is that jar-file there and class-name, path to which jar file should I provide and what class name?
Can someone help me understand? Thank you.

```
sqoop merge --new-data /apps/hive/warehouse/student/part-m-00000
--onto /apps/hive/warehouse/student/part-m-00000_copy_1
--target-dir /tmp/sqoop_merge
--jar-file /tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa/compile/9062c87c959e4090dcec5995a439b514/TIME.jar
--class-name TIME
--merge-key TIME
```

Comment: Without the code to that JAR file, we can't know either

Comment: @cricket_007 What code? My concern is, I don't know what jar file we should use or check? as in where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

I used Codegen to create the jar file later could see the class name as well. This is the code I found to create the jar file,

```
sqoop codegen \
--connect jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/<db> \
--username <username> --password <password> \ 
--table <tablename from database>
```

by the end of the execution you will get an output like,

```
18/01/16 11:44:10 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-user1/compile/6430d9e2fe24cec8b2cb13f684806ca6/student.jar
```

after which to check the class-name, I did

```
$ cd /tmp/sqoop-user1/compile/6430d9e2fe24cec8b2cb13f684806ca6/
:/tmp/sqoop-user1/compile/6430d9e2fe24cec8b2cb13f684806ca6$ ls
```

That will give you class name,jar etc,

```
student.class  student.jar  student.java
```

Thank you.